# Core code and default theme, how to model this in a git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

**The situation is as follows:**

I have developed a core set of functionalities that exist in one repository. These core files support a CMS I built for my own amusement and to use on freelance projects. The intention is to gradually refine the core files that deal with processing site visits and administration and provide a system whereby the core can be updated under any given project without breaking the project.

On any given project a set of css, html and config files also have to be developed and in order to speed up project initialisation these files are set to a default state and version controlled too though updating them on any given project in the same way as the core is out of the question for obvious reasons.

Currently to initialise a new project I pull the core files from one repo, then pull the default theme files from another, merge them and start developing, editing the theme files and leaving the core alone.

The key requirements for the solution are:

- the core can be updated independently of the default theme
- the core can be pulled into any past project without over-writing anything bespoke (except for cases of site specific developer error)
- a pull of both for project initialisation gets the latest version of the core

**The question I have to ask:**

What is the correct way to set this up? Is it set up correctly now, even though it doesn't seem so to me? Or should I have two branches in one repository, one called 'new-site-default-theme' and another called 'core' with the former pulled to initialise sites and the latter pulled to update sites? Or, is there some other way that could be considered the correct, best practice way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll split Theme and Core into different not-intersected paths, it can be common ("master") repository with separate repositories for Theme and Core added with submodules or subtree